# How can I add products to the Cart using useCart hook and linesAdd callback?

Tags: reactjs, shopify

It is my first project with Shopify and I want to add products to the Cart using useCart() hook and linesAdd() callback Shopify. But when I try to do it, all products are removed from my cart.

There is my code:

```
import {useCart} from '@shopify/hydroge'

function Product({products, quantity}) {
 
 const {lines, linesAdd} = useCart();
 
 const handleCart = () => {
  products.map((item) => {
   const line = {
    quantity: quantity,
    merchandise: item
   }
  linesAdd(lines.push(line))
  })
 }
return (
 <Button onClick=(() => handleCart()) title={"add to cart"}/>
 )
}
```

Unfortunately, after onClick event, the products firstly are pushed to the lines array and then all items are removed from the lines array.

How can I just add items without removing them?

Answer (score 0):

So, I found the solution.

If you are working with Shopify useCart() hook and want to add all products from your collection to the cart in bulk, you need the following:

```
    import {useCart} from '@shopify/hydroge'
    
    function Product({products, quantity}) {
     
     const {lines, linesAdd} = useCart();
     
     const handleCart = () => {

      const linesToCart = products.map((item)=> ({merchandiseId: item.id}))
      linesAdd(linesToCart)
      })
     }
    return (
     <Button onClick=(() => handleCart()) title={"add to cart"}/>
     )
    }
```